# AngularJS : number split

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I put a dash between the number and if it's the last digit the last number does not put a dash how I can do that please:

I have this code:

```
angular.forEach(spotcam.places, function (value, key)
{

  return strPlaces;
```

Comment: placeName is a number?

Comment: hello yes its a number  { place : 16, polygone : 0} { place : 15, polygone : 0} { place : 12, polygone : 0}

Comment: can you post expected output also? I see placeName.name will be undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can first split the number into digits and then join it by '-'

```js
var n = 123456789;
console.log(n.toString().split('').join('-'))
// First convert number to string, then split each characters, then join them back with '-'
```

Comment: I think it wants to print a readable place not the relative identifier

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` method [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows.

You can easily add your place name provider by replacing `post.place` with value provided. I provide you a `_GetPlacesFromId` example function with not found place case also.

```js
function _GetPlacesFromId(placeId) {
    return {
        "1": "Roma",
        "2": "Venezia",
        "3": "Bologna",
        "10": "Milano",
        "5": "Genova",
        "6": "Ancona",
        "7": "Modena",
        "8": "Bari",
        "9": "Napoli"
    }[placeId];
}

/* Your code initialization */
var spotcam = { places: [ {place: 1, polygone: 15}, {place: 2, polygone: 15}, {place: 3, polygone: 15}, {place: 4, polygone: 15}, {place: 5, polygone: 15}, {place: 6, polygone: 15}, {place: 7, polygone: 15}, {place: 8, polygone: 15}, {place: 9, polygone: 15} ]};

var result1 = spotcam.places.reduce((pre, post) => {
    var name = _GetPlacesFromId(post.place);
    return pre + (!name ? '' : (pre ? ' - ' : '') + name);
}, '');

var result2 = spotcam.places.reduce((pre, post) => {
    return pre + (pre ? ' - ' : '') + post.place;
}, '');

var result3 = spotcam.places.reduce((pre, post) => {
    var name = _GetPlacesFromId(post.place);
    return pre + (!name ? '' : (pre ? ' - ' : '') + post.place);
}, '');

console.log("Result 1:", result1);
console.log("Result 2:", result2);
console.log("Result 3:", result3);
```

Comment: hello matteoi want have this result  1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 just for place not for polygon

Comment: @rid7510 The `polygone` is just for example, you can use the object key do you prefer

Comment: yes Matteo  but i have  : { places: [ {place: 001 , polygone: 15}, {place: 002, polygone: 15}, {place: 003, polygone: 15}, {place: 004, polygone: 15},
i want just to have th value of place for exemple 001 - 002 - 003 - 004

Comment: @rid7510 Ok, in your question you posted a method `_GetPlacesFromId` and using it as place name in the final string.

Comment: @rid7510 I added 2 other examples, see it. The place values can be numeric or string, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @rid7510 Please update the question instead on leaving these info in comments